# Excel проверка ссылок на доступность, по кнопке

Tags: excel, макросы

Нашел скрипт, внедрил, вроде работает.
Хочу сделать скрипт чтобы проверять сайты на работает или нет, ну заходит или нет.

Вообщем, нажимаешь кнопку проверить, идет проверка, и высвечивается надпись перед тем как присвоить статус у урла. Проверка..., так вот если на сайт заходит то меняется надпись на РАБОТАЕТ, если не заходит, сайт в блоке или не существует, то надпись должна меняться на НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, но она не меняется, у меня остается  Проверка...

Как бы это проверить можно.

Использую такой скрипт.

```
Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim winHttpReq As Object
    Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    On Error GoTo l_error
        
    For Each cell In Range("Таблица1").Columns(1).Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
      
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Проверка..."
        Call winHttpReq.Open("GET", cell.Value, False)
        
        Call winHttpReq.Send
        If winHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "РАБОТАЕТ"
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "НЕ РАБОТАЕТ"
        End If
        End If
        
l_error:

    Next cell
End Sub
```

На крине видно самый последний урл он не корректный, скрипт останавливает работу и выводит ошибку, если допустим в середине такой урл будет, то будет плохо, как бы это исправить, чтобы скрипт вывел ошибку что не корректный урл и попер дальше проверять.

А так же видно снизу 2 урл, по идеи на сайт не заходит, должно присвоиться надпись, Не работает, не заменяет Проверка..., надпись.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже чуть доработал и добавил такой код, If cell.Value <> "" Then, который проверяет только те поля в таблице в которых есть урл. А точнее хоть что-то )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, ловите, помогли доработать код до идеала.
Теперь в инете можно будет найти нормальный код ), этот.

```
Function GetURLstatus(ByVal URL$) As Long
    On Error Resume Next: URL$ = Replace(URL$, "\", "/")
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", URL, "False"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    xmlhttp.send
    GetURLstatus = Val(xmlhttp.Status)
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Function

Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
For Each cell In Range("Таблица1").Columns(1).Cells
If cell.Value <> "" Then
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Проверка..."
    s = cell.Value
    If UCase(Left(s, 4)) = "HTTP" Then
    ss = GetURLstatus(s)
    Select Case ss
    Case 200: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "РАБОТАЕТ"
    'Case 400 To 600: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "НЕ РАБОТАЕТ"
    Case Else: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "НЕ РАБОТАЕТ"
    End Select
    Else
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Некорректная ссылка"
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```